# How to get Feature Type Details properties from jsonColumn field using sql view query on GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I have sqlserver db table that contains only two column one is entityId column and second one is entityJson.

So on GeoServer I have written following Sql View Query i.e.

```
SELECT 
    entityId,
    JSON_VALUE(entityJson,'$.EntityName') As EntityName,    
    geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + 
    CAST(JSON_VALUE(entityJson,'$.Lat') As CHAR(20)) + ' ' + 
    CAST(JSON_VALUE(entityJson,'$.Long') AS CHAR(20)) + ')',4326) as geometria 
FROM dbo.Entities
```

From above query On Edit Sqlview page attribute as EntityName is display after click on Refresh button I get the following:

[image: Edit SQL View Attribute]

But on Feature Type Details property EntityName is not coming.

[image: FeatureType Details Property]

Any help to get property from table jsoncolumn on GeoServer by SQL View?

Comment: I just tried this in GeoServer 2.11.2, and I cannot replicate your problem. All three columns are shown. Of course, this is with a very small test data set. If you run your view as a query in SSMS, does it return what you think it should?

Comment: (Also, you have put your X and Y in the wrong order - it should be `(Long, Lat)` not `(Lat, Long)` but that shouldn't make any difference with regards to your problem.)